# sequence of elements in $\ell_2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the sequence in $\displaystyle{ \ell _2 (\mathbb N ) }$

$$ (x^k)_k = \sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{1}{i} e_i $$

where $\displaystyle{ e_i \in \ell_2 }$ is the $i-\text{th}$ unit vector in $\ell_2$ ,i.e. $\displaystyle{ (e_i)_j = \delta_{ij} }$

Does this sequence converge in $\ell_2$ ? And if it converges can we find its limit ?

Edit: I correct the defition of $(x^k$.  I used superscripts, instead of subscripts, since each $x^k$ is itself sequence.

Comment: Did you try to calculate $\|x^k\|^2$?

Comment: Yes I did it, the sequence converge to $x=(1, \frac{1}{2}, \cdots , \frac{1}{k} , \frac{1}{k+1} , \cdots ) \in \ell_2 $ right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
$$\lVert x^{m+n}-x^m\rVert^2_{\ell_2}=\sum_{j=m+1}^{m+n}\frac 1{j^2}\leqslant \sum_{j\geqslant m+1}\frac 1{j^2}\to 0, \mbox{ as }m\to \infty,$$
the sequence $(x^{n},n\geqslant 1)$ is Cauchy in the complete normed space $\ell_2$. Therefore, the sequence is convergent to some $x\in\ell_2$. We have if $i$ is an integer that $\langle x,e_i\rangle=\lim_{n\to \infty}\langle x^{n},e_i\rangle=\frac 1i$, which gives the expression of the limit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer!